# Ngx-translate fail to share into subcomponent

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

my translate module load at shared/header.module.ts
mainly because I doing html language switcher together in same place.

header.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: CustomTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),

  exports: [
    TranslateModule,
    HeaderComponent
  ]
})
```

Then I export it

At leftnavigation.component.html, footer.component.html, rightbar.component.html
I import and successfully get the translation value

At leftbarnavigation.ts I also export it

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule,    
  ]
})
```

Nothing done at app.module.ts, since my main translate is setting at header.module.ts,
I just do the normal import and export

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

at app-routing.module.ts
I also do the import and export

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    data: { pageTitle: "Home" },
    children: [
      {
        path: "dashboard",
        loadChildren: "./dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule",
      }, {
        path: "portfolio",
        loadChildren: "./portfolio/portfolio.module#PortfolioModule",
      },
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [    TranslateModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [    TranslateModule, RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

then portfolio.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule,    
    PortfolioRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class PortfolioModule { }
```

Then portfolio-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'portfolio-list',
    component: PortfolioListComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [TranslateModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [TranslateModule, RouterModule]
})
export class PortfolioRoutingModule { }
```

however, when I open my page   /portfolio/portfolio-list

The translation doesn't taking any effect...
Translation fail to shared into this page....
I'm using angular 6.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Does the `PortfolioListComponent` load properly? Maybe you forgot to declare it in a module, for example in the `PortfolioModule`?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule,    
    PortfolioRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [PortfolioListComponent],
})
export class PortfolioModule { }
```